# How do I prevent ConEmu auto-attaching to every single cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, conemu

I don't want ConEmu to attach to every cmd I open, but this is how it works now. I remember that I told ConEmu to do this, but I don't want it anymore. Maybe I just overlooked something, but I've read all the settings pages and I couldn't find an option to disable it. Am I missing something?

How do I prevent ConEmu from attaching every single cmd.exe I open?

My ConEmu version is 121109 x86, on winXPproSp3x86.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings -> Startup -> ComSpec

Press "Unregister" button.

Comment: I was overlooking it after all! Thank you very much!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in current ConEmu. Even if `"C:\Program Files (x86)\clink\0.4.7\clink.bat" inject --autorun --profile ~\clink` is the current content, it is still auto attached. It seems that there is some other setting. Maybe, I have chosen once to attach a cmd.exe window and that is stored at other places in the config

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for an answer to why doing:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe '.\MyScript.ps1'
```

within PowerShell in a ConEmu would launch it in a new ConEmu tab rather than cmd.exe (ComSpec).

To stop ConEmu from doing this, within Settings → Features, under "In-console options", untick "Inject ConEmuHk".